# XForms: Possible to modify HTML element attribute ? (I'm using XSLTForms)

Tags: dom, xforms, xsltforms

Does XForms have a mechanism for manipulating attributes of the resultant HTML?
I guess I mean emitting HTML dynamically and setting the attributes as part of that.

I know that using a xf:repeat - you can effectively emit HTML elements, but I can't work out if this would stretch to attributes?

I'm using XSLTForms as the implementation - so maybe this support hooks for Javascript to do this if there isn't a built-in way?

The reason to ask specifically - I would like to work with the [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element (and some other HTML5 elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is named AVT for Attribute Value Template. As in XSLT, just wrap XPath expressions into curly braces like in `<div class="proto{$myclass}">`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from Alain Couthures - I was able to put together the following. Sharing in case others find it interesting.

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="xsltforms/xsltforms.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<html
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
   <head>
      <title>Podcast Player</title>
      <xf:model>
         <xf:instance xmlns="">
            <data>
               <url/>
            </data>
         </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="feed" src="https://podcasts.files.bbci.co.uk/b05qqhqp.rss"/>
      </xf:model>
   <style><![CDATA[
        * { font-family: arial; background-color:black; color: white }
   ]]></style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1><xf:output ref="instance('feed')/channel/title"/></h1>
        <blockquote><xf:output ref="instance('feed')/channel/description"/></blockquote>
        <xf:select1 ref="url" appearance="full">
            <xf:itemset nodeset="instance('feed')/channel/item">
                <xf:label ref="title"/>
                <xf:value ref="enclosure/@url"/>
            </xf:itemset>
        </xf:select1>
       <audio src="{url}" controls="true"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

The relevant bit to this post is the "audio" tag and in particular the "{url}" attribute template.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

For those that wish to try this example, you'll need XSLTForms : https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XSLTForms , other XForms implementations are available.

Note: save the file with the extension '.xhtml' and place behind a webserver of your choice.
For instance using test HTTP servers: [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), [python](https://www.educba.com/python-3-http-server/) etc.